# Does the prime symbol have any meaning if it stands at the end of a sigma term?

Tags: notation, covariance

I try to make sense of equation (3) in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1207/s15327752jpa8402_02):

$$S_W=\frac{\sum_{i=1}\sum_{j=1}^{J_i}(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_i)(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_i)'}{N-1}$$

"Equation 3 is used to compute the (pooled) within covariance matrix (SW)."

What does the prime symbol at the right side of the equation mean in this case? Does it simply describe the end of what is affected by the sigma? Or is it something that I need to address explicitly when translating this equation into code?

Comment: No, in this case, it is the **transposition** sign in order to have the product of a line vector with a column vector yielding in all cases a number.

Comment: Thanks alot! This answers my question